# Custom Event Design in Java

Tags: java, events

I need to implement classes to support a custom event capable of passing varying types/amounts of data based on the event type. For example,

With event Type A I need to pass 2 String names.
With event Type B I need to pass 3 String names and a double.

2 designs I've found:

1. An extension of EventObject that contains fields and methods for all of possible data (fields not required for some event types are left blank).

   ```
   // event constructors
   public MyEvent(Object source, int type, String a, String b) {}

   public MyEvent(Object source, int type, String a, String b, String c, double d) {}
   ```
2. An extension of EventObject that contains a parameter for an EventInfo object. EventInfo is a base class for change info. Methods firing specific events will pass along subclasses of EventInfo containing the necessary change information (listeners would be required to downcast).

   ```
   // event constructors
   public MyEvent(Object source, int type, EventInfo info) {}

   // base class for event info
   public class EventInfo {}
   ```

What other designs exist for implementing this? What are the pros and cons of each?

Thanks.

Comment: 3. Subclass each event type from a base class event type.

Comment: +1 to @GilbertLeBlanc's comment - same design as with the Exceptions, which are essentially events of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common design would be to include a Map in your event class to keep parameters as well as a field to show the event type. Your event interface would therefore look like this:

```
public interface Event [
    public Object getParameter(String key);
    public void setParameter(String key, Object parameter);
    public String getType();
}
```

In your event handler class you can use getParameter() and getType() to retrieve the event's parameters and event type.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to try Scala, this is what "case" classes are mostly used for. You would define them as:

```
sealed trait SomeEvent
case class YourEvent( a: String, b: String ) extends SomeEvent
case class YourOtherEvent( a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Double  ) extends SomeEvent
```

and then you can just use them in your "event processor" by pattern matching:

```
class EventProcessor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  def receive = {

    case YourEvent( a: String, b: String ) =>

        // handle it    

    case YourOtherEvent( a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Double ) =>

        // handle it    

    case unknown => log.debug( "got an unknown event => " + unknown )
  }
}
```

Not sure what you mean by `int type`, but if that is the type if the event, it can be just a typed class instead.

An `Object source` would probably be something like `source: ActorRef`, which you actually can reply to, and also do not need to pass as a parameter (if using Scala/AKKA, it creates and keeps that reference for you):

```
    case YourEvent( a: String, b: String, c: String, d: Double ) =>

        // handle it
        ...
        //reply to sender (e.g. source)
        sender ! YourReply( ... )
```

---

The example above uses a tiny portion of AKKA, but it does not have to, as the pattern matching on case classes is a built in Scala feature.

Take the above as just *a different way of looking at the problem* you are solving.